# Cloud Console Datastore filters

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I recently switched from JDO to Objectify in an effort to simplify some of my backend (I'm a beginner with App Engine and server side stuff in general).

I have an entity, AppVersion that used to look like this in Cloud Console:
[image]

When I switched to objectify, it no longer has the option to filter by minVersionRequired and looks like this:
[image]

Entity Code (Before)

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class AppVersion {

@Id
private String applicationName;
private int minVersionRequired;

public String getApplicationName() {
    return applicationName;
}
public int getMinVersionRequired() {
    return minVersionRequired;
}
public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
    this.applicationName = applicationName;
}
public void setminVersionRequired(int minVersionRequired) {
    this.minVersionRequired = minVersionRequired;
}
}
```

Entity Code (After)

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class AppVersion {

@Id
private String applicationName;
private int minVersionRequired;

public String getApplicationName() {
    return applicationName;
}
public int getMinVersionRequired() {
    return minVersionRequired;
}
public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
    this.applicationName = applicationName;
}
public void setminVersionRequired(int minVersionRequired) {
    this.minVersionRequired = minVersionRequired;
}
}
```

Endpoint Code (Before) *Note that this was autogenerated in Eclipse*

```
import com.companionfree.zooperthemeviewer.EMF;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPACursorHelper;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Api(name = "appversionendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "company.com", ownerName = "company.com", packagePath = "app"))
public class AppVersionEndpoint {

/**
 * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
 * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
 *
 * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
 * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "listAppVersion")
public CollectionResponse<AppVersion> listAppVersion(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<AppVersion> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getEntityManager();
        Query query = mgr
                .createQuery("select from AppVersion as AppVersion");
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<AppVersion>) query.getResultList();
        cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

        // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
        // for lazy fetch.
        for (AppVersion obj : execute)
            ;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<AppVersion> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
}

/**
 * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
 * @return The entity with primary key id.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "getAppVersion")
public AppVersion getAppVersion(@Named("id") String id) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    AppVersion appversion = null;
    try {
        appversion = mgr.find(AppVersion.class, id);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return appversion;
}

/**
 * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
 * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP POST method.
 *
 * @param appversion the entity to be inserted.
 * @return The inserted entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "insertAppVersion")
public AppVersion insertAppVersion(AppVersion appversion) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        if (containsAppVersion(appversion)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.persist(appversion);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return appversion;
}

/**
 * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
 * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP PUT method.
 *
 * @param appversion the entity to be updated.
 * @return The updated entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "updateAppVersion")
public AppVersion updateAppVersion(AppVersion appversion) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        if (!containsAppVersion(appversion)) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
        }
        mgr.persist(appversion);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return appversion;
}

/**
 * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
 * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "removeAppVersion")
public void removeAppVersion(@Named("id") String id) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        AppVersion appversion = mgr.find(AppVersion.class, id);
        mgr.remove(appversion);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
}

private boolean containsAppVersion(AppVersion appversion) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        AppVersion item = mgr.find(AppVersion.class,
                appversion.getApplicationName());
        if (item == null) {
            contains = false;
        }
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return contains;
}

private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return EMF.get().createEntityManager();
}

}
```

Endpoints Code (After) *Note this was created by me in Android Studio*

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Named;

import static com.company.backend.OfyService.ofy;

@Api(name = "appversionendpoint", version = "v1", namespace =
@ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "backend.company.com",
    ownerName = "backend.company.com", packagePath = ""))
public class AppVersionEndpoint {

@ApiMethod(name = "listAppVersion")
public CollectionResponse<AppVersion> listAppVersion() {
    List<AppVersion> execute;
   execute =  ofy().load().type(AppVersion.class).list();
return CollectionResponse.<AppVersion> builder().setItems(execute).build();

}


/**
 * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
 * @return The entity with primary key id (null if DNE).
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "getAppVersion")
public AppVersion getAppVersion(@Named("id") String id) {
    return ofy().load().type(AppVersion.class).id(id).now();

}

/**
 * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
 * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP POST method.
 *
 * @param appversion the entity to be inserted.
 * @return The inserted entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "insertAppVersion")
public AppVersion insertAppVersion(AppVersion appversion) {
    AppVersion exist = getAppVersion(appversion.getApplicationName());
    AppVersion result;
    if (exist == null) {
        ofy().save().entity(appversion).now();
        result = getAppVersion(appversion.getApplicationName());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(appversion.getApplicationName() + " exists already");
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

I would much prefer to have it filterable like it was originally but I don't know why it is different.  Can anyone fill me in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here: firstly, by default, Objectify assumes you don't want to index your class's properties (this keeps your datastore indexes lean and mean).  Secondly, I believe the new Datastore console's filter UI only shows properties which have indexes associated with them (as you can't filter on unindexed properties).

So, if you want to be able to query or sort by *minVersionRequired*, just add an `@Index` annotation to that field in your POJO and Objectify will use the `setIndexedProperty()` method in underlying Entity class within the low level Datastore API.

If you want to index all the properties in your class by default, you can put the `@Index` annotation on the class and then `@Unindex` any you specifically don't want indexed.

Comment: Doesn't appear to have worked.  Maybe it takes some time?  I shouldn't need to re-add all the entities, right?

Comment: Hey, what do you know...I came back and checked a few hours later and the changes took hold.  Thanks!